# Are there any Google devices that support file based capabilities in their default kernel?

Tags: rooting, root-access, security, file-system, kernel

If I systemless root (no modification done to `/system` partition) a Nexus device, would I be able to able to set [capabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capability-based_security#POSIX_vs._Capsicum_capabilities) on executables without changing the original kernel binary ?

I often want to manage files without restrictions from my terminal *(require`CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH`)*. However, I also want to not use the superuser.
The required things are tools for setting caps along kernel support for using them *(it doesn't rely on other user space things)*.

The problem is, I don’t own such device. So I can’t tell if it would work on any of `Nexus 5X Nexus 6P Nexus 9 Pixel C`.

Comment: I was also unable to find a nexus emulator…

Comment: I doubt it... Since Android uses Bionic libc and not the standard GNU libc (glibc) library, it is not even close to POSIX compliant. You might be able to compile your own kernel with a different libc like CrystaX NDK instead of Bionic, but I don't know if those features are in that either.

Comment: @acejavelin : the userland part is only required for setting extended attributes containing capabilities. Everything else is kernel side. I just noticed the`/system/bin/ping`command isn’t setuid on my real samsung device, suggesting`CAP_NET_RAW`. However, I won’t root a real device and I don’t know which tool I can use to see the relevant informations, so I can’t check.

Comment: Why would you not root a Nexus device? It is intended for that and does not void your warranty. It is very simple to restore any Nexus device to it's default, unrooted and locked state, the device is basically unbrickable.

Comment: @acejavelin : I don’t own a nexus device… My aim is security research and google only reward for it’s own devices. So I need to know if the kernel of one of the devices in my question support using capabilities xattr. What I’m seeing on my galaxy tab is probably only samsung related. **If I don’t involve rooting in my question it might be closed as unclear**.

Comment: OK, I thought from your question's verbiage that you had one but wanted to know if it also worked on all other Nexus models. I misunderstood that this was just a hypothetical or research question.

Comment: @acejavelin : I wrote`The problem of course is I don’t own such device.`In my question.

Answer (score 1):

Though the question is old, it keeps on appearing on top of ***Unanswered (my tags)*** questions. So I think I should answer this :)

### AOSP'S SUPPORT FOR CAPABILITIES:

Question is specifically about Google devices, I have never used a Google device. However what I can say for sure is that Linux (process) capabilities must have been enabled on most of the devices (if not all) running as low as Android 1.6. Reference is found in [`init`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-1.6_r1/init/readme.txt#81) and [`system_server`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/ca63bb72ef82d392c759a2bd507b7410ea82eacf), both very primary components of AOSP. In Android 4.2, for instance, [`installd`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/812b19a425b8304ac9e5408cc8ceb9f363c72559) - another core component - was made to run with dropped capabilities.

[Filesystem capabilities](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/e9e74f3c881bd73bd86be4db8b12200a61f143e1) were one of the major [Security Enhancements in Android 4.3](https://source.android.com/security/enhancements/enhancements43) which removed `set-uid`/`set-gid` from binaries like [`run-as`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/fe8135739c5a9195e74786205c077964ba4f9c44), setting file capabilities on them. This caused [revolutionary changes](https://chainfire.eu/articles/768) in Android's rooting journey.

Support for [Ambient capabilities](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/24b29132a017f7fbfd009c3e6aec499d1b815dbf) was added in Android 8 which [discourages](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/ambient) the use of file capabilities:

> File capabilities, in turn, present a security risk since any process executing a file with file capabilities will be able to gain those capabilities.

Many `init` services depend on them e.g. [`storaged`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r47/storaged/storaged.rc#3), including my own [`sshd`](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209919/218526) and [`dnscrypt-proxy`](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/207647/218526) services.

### KERNEL'S SUPPORT FOR CAPABILITIES:

Coming to the kernel part, building kernel without [capabilities](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) isn't optional:

> From kernel 2.5.27 to kernel 2.6.26, capabilities were an optional kernel component, and could be enabled/disabled via the **CONFIG_SECURITY_CAPABILITIES** kernel configuration option.

And:

> In kernels before Linux 2.6.33, file capabilities were an optional feature configurable via the **CONFIG_SECURITY_FILE_CAPABILITIES** option. Since Linux 2.6.33, the configuration option has been removed and file capabilities are always part of the kernel.

The oldest common kernel version on Android repositories is 2.6.39 which [includes](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/refs/heads/deprecated/android-2.6.39/security/commoncap.c#37) support for file capabilities too.

Support for filesystem capabilities on kernel side must have been [delayed](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/c0ecb5bdbf465ef05ed3379c13ff9a4245412ce7) from some OEMs but they had to switch, because otherwise functionalities would break. For instance [`surfaceflinger`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/3a29e344b0d0b184954d505a58e61141300e0dd2) (Android's [surface composer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_server)) won't work without file capabilities since Android 7.1.

Mainline Linux kernel 4.3 was patched in in Sep'15 for Ambient (process) capabilities, [backported](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/ambient#required-patches) to Android kernel 3.18 and 4.1 in 2016. So they are necessarily a part of kernel.

### CONCLUSION:

On Linux distros, a [very few](https://blog.wireshark.org/2010/02/running-wireshark-as-you/) programs make use of Linux capabilities. Though there is [`pam_cap`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/libs/libcap/libcap.git/tree/pam_cap/capability.conf), mostly (or all?) distros still use `set-uid` on `su`, `sudo`, `ping`, `mount`, `passwd` and so on.  But on Android capabilities are deeply integrated in framework and core services. Removing them would require editing hundreds or may be thousands of lines in AOSP and kernel source. It makes no sense that an OEM (particularly Google, who developed AOSP and modified Linux kernel for Android) doesn't make use of this *free-of-cost* security feature when it's readily available in Android kernel. It's a pure OS related feature, doesn't demand any extra hardware support. So any phone from any manufacturer must have capabilities supported.

---

**QUESTIONS:**

> would I be able to able to set capabilities on executables without changing the original kernel binary?

Yes, you must be.

> The required things are tools for setting caps ...

I have been using `capsh`, `getcap`, `setcap`, `getpcaps` from [`libcap`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/libs/libcap/libcap.git) and `netcap`, `pscap` from [`libcap-ng`](https://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/libcap-ng/) without any problems. But I prefer Ambient capabilities, those are easy to configure and don't depend on any filesystem features like **Extended Attributes** as in case of file capabilities. You can also use `listxattr`, `getxattr`, `setxattr` and `removexattr` tools from [`xattr_syscall_wrapper`](https://github.com/SoftwearDevelopment/xattr_syscall_wrapper) to manipulate `security.capability` or any other XATTR directly.

From your comment:

> I just noticed the `/system/bin/ping` command isn’t `setuid` on my real Samsung device, suggesting `CAP_NET_RAW`

Android's [ping](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/be341cc348257a07c68bcbfdc526835d49283329) neither has `set-uid` nor `CAP_NET_RAW`. It creates a special [non-RAW](https://lkml.org/lkml/2011/5/18/305) socket [`IPPROTO_ICMP`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/icmp.7.html) which - unlike [`IPPROTO_RAW`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/raw.7.html) - doesn't require any privileges.

---

**FURTHER REFERENCES:**

In addition to 10+ references given above, here are a few other parts of AOSP code supporting and making use of Linux capabilities:

- **Core components:** Bionic `libc`, `init`, `trusty` (OS)
- **External components:** `libcap`, `libcap-ng`
- **Daemons / services:** `zygote` (forked apps and `system_server`), `hostapd`, `wpa_supplicant`, `dnsmasq`, `logd`, `netd` (`NetLink` manager, private DNS), `debuggerd` (test), `sdcard` daemon, `performanced`, `incidentd`, `mtpd`, `traced_probes` (perfetto), `racoon` (IPSec), `wificond`, a number of HAL daemons including `rild`.
- **Executables:** `reboot` (init), `dumpstate`, `tcpdump`, `strace`, `iputils` (`ping`, `traceroute` etc.)
- **Minijail:** A dedicated sandboxing tool and library which revolves around capabilities. `adbd` makes use of this library to drop privileges.
- **SELinux** uses `capability` class to grant / deny capabilities to domains.

It concludes that Android highly depends on Linux capabilities, it's not a ***little-used*** feature.

---

**RELATED:**

- [What special privileges “/system/xbin/su” does have w.r.t. root access?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/207902/218526)
- [Permissions, Root User and Linux Capabilities: Linux vs. Android](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=77437874&postcount=6)

Comment: Doesn’t answer anything at all. Everything you stated is known. The point of the question is since it’s little‑used is wether Google branded devices include it.